# Issue using eval function on value in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, eval

Here is my code. It is the last eval line that is returning a syntax error

```
def format_date():
    month_abrv = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul',
                  'Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
    print('''This program takes an input in the format MM/DD/YYYY(ex:09/23/2014)
and outputs date in format DD Mth, YYYY (ex: 23 Sep, 2014)''')

    date_string = input('\nInput date in format MM/DD/YYYY  ')
    date_list = date_string.split('/')

    date_list[0] = eval(date_list[0])

format_date()
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Python ICS 140/FormatDate.py", line 16, in <module>
    format_date()
  File "C:/Python34/Python ICS 140/FormatDate.py", line 14, in format_date
    date_list[0] = eval(date_list[0])
  File "<string>", line 1
    09
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: *Why* are you trying to use `eval` instead of e.g. [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)?

Comment: Realized that python is trying to read value 09 as an octal and not decimal. Any ideas on how to change any digits below 10 i.e. 09,08,07... into 9,8,7 for this piece of code?

Comment: @LukasGraf I am taking an intro to python course and we haven't used datetime.strptime yet. Would there be a way to do it without using that function?

Comment: Use `int(token)` on every token in `date_list` to parse it into an integer, and then use those three integers with the `datetime()` constructor to create a `datetime` object.

Comment: say date_list[0] = 09 then running int(date_list[0]) returns '9'      This is exactly what I want, but why can't I then eval that number? For instance I can't write eval(int(date_list[0])) because I get another syntax error?

Comment: eval needs an expression (either a piece of code or a string ) https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval It fails because you supply an int!

Comment: I just figured this out after messing with the code a bit. Thanks user3885927!

Comment: Don't use `eval()` on (parts of) user supplied data unless you know what you're doing. Use `int()` if you want to interpret an integer.

Comment: I question an intro course that introduces `eval` at all.

Comment: @chepner why do you say that? Just out of curiosity

Comment: `eval` is easy enough to abuse without introducing it to programmers who don't yet know enough to use it correctly and only when necessary.

Comment: I guess I mostly ask because I am wondering where someone may run into issues with using that instead of using something else. Is it just convention to use int() first when that is all that is necessary?

Comment: It's not just convention, it's a good practice and in some cases it's the only applicable way as often the code is not running with the same privileges as the user (e.g. a web application).

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little more digging I found that Python interprets numbers starting with 0s as octal numbers. using the int() function to change '09' to 9 worked in this case.

Comment: Btw this only applies to Python 2.x, not Python 3.x.

Comment: I have and have only had Python 3.4.1. Are you sure that it is different in 3.x?

Comment: You can test it very easily and include the test results in the answer. On 2.7 typing `033` into the interactive interpreter renters `27`, i.e. it's interpreted as octal. On 3.3 it fails with `SyntaxError`. I don't have 3.4 at hand, but if you're right, then 3.4 introduces it for compatibility purpose.